# Trying to receive data from serial port on Simulink, the whole program just shut down immediately

Tags: matlab, serial-port, simulink

I was using the simulink blocks 'serial configuration' and 'serial receive' to receive data from a Xbee module plugged into a serial comport. The Xbee module is supposed to send a string of data at 10Hz to the comport. As i run the program, simulink immediately crashes and shut down. The error message is EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION . How could i possibly solve this?

Comment: What operating system, version of MATLAB, and version of java are you running? ('version -java' from command line).  Have you tried connecting to the serial port and reading data just using MATLAB functions rather than going through Simulink?

Comment: i am running it on Windows 7, matlab 2012b, and java version is  1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. I have tried it on a few computers but all faced the same issue. However, if i tried to read the data on matlab function, it won't crash.

Comment: If it happens on multiple computers then it may be an issue with the way your Simulink model is set up. Have you tried running some Simulink serial examples? I think there's a loopback test for serial.

Comment: what is a loopback test for serial? How to do it? Thanks for the information!

Comment: A loopback test is when you connect the send/receive pins on a serial port (you can get a plug for it), so you send data out and recieve it back through the same port. See: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/instrument/building-simulink-models-to-send-and-receive-data.html